# ua-parser works fine with single thread, fails when multithreading

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am attempting to use the R implementation of [ua-parser](https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-r) in parallel using mclappy on an AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu 14.04 and R 3.2.2. I can't seem to wrap my head around the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Running the following works just fine.

```
parsed_ua <- as.data.frame(parse_agents(data))
```

However, when I attempt to run the process in parallel I hit a roadblock and the warning messages that result are uninformative.

```
parsed_ua <- 
  do.call(
    rbind, mclapply(
      split(data, rep(1:5,each=2)), 
       function(x){
         x <- as.data.frame(parse_agents(x))
         return(x)
         }, mc.cores = 5))
```

Returns

> ```
> In mclapply(split(data, rep(1:5,each=2)), function(x) { :
>   all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
> ```

Here is some sample data:

```
data <- c("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; en-us; SAMSUNG-SGH-I537 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/1.5 Chrome/28.0.1500.94 Mobile Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B466 Safari/600.1.4",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B466 Safari/600.1.4",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B466 Safari/600.1.4",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 4_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8C148 Safari/6533.18.5",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; en-us; SAMSUNG-SGH-I537 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/1.5 Chrome/28.0.1500.94 Mobile Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B466 Safari/600.1.4"
    )
```

Comment: you'll need to add logging code (and some tactical `tryCatch()` statements) or run w/o `mclapply` for a bit to see what strings toss errors. Perhaps @oliver-keyes has some ideas as well.

Comment: @hrbrmstr - thanks for the advice. I tried a few random tryCatch() statements without any luck earlier but they were far from tactical. One note, the script runs fine as a single thread while splitting the dataset, but fails almost instantly once it reaches the mclapply portion (I typically see 3-10 R processes fire up for just a split second before everything cuts out at once and the R terminal throws a warning message. I attribute the variation due to latency)